# XPTable values added to combobox column not showing

Tags: c#, combobox

I am using an XPTable (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11596/XPTable-NET-ListView-meets-Java-s-JTable) and try to add a comboBox column. 

 The comboBox column shows in the table but has no dropdown items to select. 
Here is my code:

```
        tblOrdModel.Rows.Clear();
        var combo = new XPTable.Editors.ComboBoxCellEditor();
        List<Supplier> sups = new DataRepository().GetSuppliers();
        foreach (var s in sups)
        {
            combo.Items.Add(s);
        }
        combo.SelectedIndex = 0;
        combo.DropDownStyle = XPTable.Editors.DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
        colOrdModel.Columns[4].Editor = combo;
        XPTable.Models.Row r = new Row();
        r.Tag = tli.ItemRawMaterial;
        r.Cells.Add(new Cell(tli.ItemRawMaterial.RM_StockCode));
        r.Cells.Add(new Cell(tli.ItemRawMaterial.StockDescription));
        r.Cells.Add(new Cell(tli.ItemQty));
        r.Cells.Add(new Cell(tli.ItemDueDate.ToShortDateString()));
        r.Cells.Add(new Cell(combo.Items[0]));
        tblOrdModel.Rows.Add(r);
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. I had the column not set to editable...set in designer or with:

```
colOrdModel.Columns[4].Editable=true;
```

Hope it helps someone else!